# how to append large Images in Form data

Tags: javascript, image, image-uploading

I want to pass Images though Ajax...but when I append multiple larger images of 3-4 MB's my image is not getting inserted into form Data...also there is and error of Maximum limit reached when I access it in the image handler...I am uploading 12 images at once and the max limit per image is 4 MB..

```
    var formData = new FormData();
var uploadfiles = $("#ImagesUpload").get(0);
var uploadedfiles = uploadfiles.files;

for (var i = 0; i < uploadedfiles.length; i++)
{
   formData.append('file', uploadedfiles[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Check you web server file upload limit size.

Comment: hey @Subbu is there any way to send image files to server side..without using Formdata

Comment: In Html 5 we have some way in which we dont have to use formdata.
In your case you can use chunk uploader to upload large file instead of uploading all at one go.

Comment: hello, did you find the solution?